Book recommendations for multi-variable analysis.
The only rigorous multi-variable analysis that I have read is from Rudin's PMA and it was only two chapters but I am sure that there are more theorems that calculus 3 course cover that was not in the final two chapters from Rudin's PMA.
I need to review multi-variable calculus again because it has been so long since I encountered anything related directly to it but I think it would be better if I read a whole book dedicated to multi-variable analysis than the two chapters from Rudin's and a calculus 3 book.
So I want to ask for rigorous math book for function of several variables and multi-variable analysis.

Both volumes of Multidimensional Real Analysis by Duistermaat and Kolk

Zorich Analysis, but it's more difficult than baby Rudin.

Calculus on manifolds by Spivak. It has very nice set of exercises
